# XBAP,System.Security.SecurityException ,how i can work out this?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Hi All i am doing a test to host my WPF app on the WEB with a Databinding but when i deply the file i receive this error:

---

Startup URI: C:\Users\Mamma\Desktop\New folder (2)\WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap
Application Identity: file:///C:/Users/Mamma/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap#WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap, Version=1.0.0.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=706641813ca14f92, processorArchitecture=msil/WpfBrowserApplication1.exe, Version=1.0.0.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=706641813ca14f92, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(PermissionSet permSet, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at WpfBrowserApplication1.Page1.Page_Load(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowPos(HandleRef hWnd, HandleRef hWndInsertAfter, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 cx, Int32 cy, Int32 flags)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.RootBrowserWindow.ResizeMove(Int32 xDeviceUnits, Int32 yDeviceUnits, Int32 widthDeviceUnits, Int32 heightDeviceUnits)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.RootBrowserWindow.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Application.b__1a(Object window)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.StartDispatcherInBrowser(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)

The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission
The first permission that failed was:

The demand was for:

The granted set of the failing assembly was:

The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
WpfBrowserApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
The method that caused the failure was:
Void Page_Load(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
The Url of the assembly that failed was:
file:///C:/Users/Mamma/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/ZAZ7NYD7.ADV/EK4BYT8K.7XG/wpfb..xbap_706641813ca14f92_0001.0000_30eb636da5b21cd2/WpfBrowserApplication1.EXE

---

PresentationHost.exe v3.0.6920.4902 built by: NetFXw7 - C:\Windows\System32\PresentationHost.exe
ntdll.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
kernel32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
KERNELBASE.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ADVAPI32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
msvcrt.dll v7.0.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
sechost.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
RPCRT4.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
USER32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
GDI32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LPK.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
USP10.dll v1.0626.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ole32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
mscoree.dll v4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000) - C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll
SHLWAPI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
WININET.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
Normaliz.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll
urlmon.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
CRYPT32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
MSASN1.dll v6.1.7600.16415 (win7_gdr.090828-1615) - C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
iertutil.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
SHELL32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
IMM32.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
MSCTF.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
mzvkbd3.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\PROGRA~1\KASPER~1\KASPER~1\mzvkbd3.dll
kloehk.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\PROGRA~1\KASPER~1\KASPER~1\kloehk.dll
PresentationHost_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationHost_v0400.dll
MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll v10.00.30319.1 - C:\Windows\System32\MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll
VERSION.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\VERSION.dll
PSAPI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
CRYPTBASE.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
uxtheme.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
DockShellHook.dll v(null) - C:\Program Files\Stardock\ObjectDock\DockShellHook.dll
CLBCatQ.DLL v2001.12.8530.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
CRYPTSP.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTSP.dll
rsaenh.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
RpcRtRemote.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\RpcRtRemote.dll
PROPSYS.dll v7.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
comctl32.dll v6.10 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\comctl32.dll
SspiCli.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\SspiCli.dll
profapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
ws2_32.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\ws2_32.DLL
NSI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
dnsapi.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.DLL
iphlpapi.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\iphlpapi.DLL
WINNSI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\WINNSI.DLL
dfshim.dll v4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000) - C:\Windows\System32\dfshim.dll
mscoreei.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
clr.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
dwmapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll
msxml3.dll v8.110.7600.16605 - C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll
ieproxy.dll v8.00.7600.16625 (win7_gdr.100629-1617) - C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
SXS.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\SXS.DLL
PresentationHostProxy.dll v4.0.31106.0 built by: Main - C:\Windows\System32\PresentationHostProxy.dll
mshtml.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll
msls31.dll v3.10.349.0 - C:\Windows\System32\msls31.dll
msimtf.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msimtf.dll
Captlib.dll v8.0.0.36 - C:\Program Files\Babylon\Babylon-Pro\Captlib.dll
OLEACC.dll v7.0.0.0 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\OLEACC.dll
IEFRAME.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\IEFRAME.dll
scrchpg.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\scrchpg.dll
jscript.dll v5.8.7600.16385 - C:\Windows\System32\jscript.dll
klscav.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\klscav.dll
MSVCR80.dll v8.00.50727.4927 - C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5\MSVCR80.dll
prremote.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\prremote.dll
MSVCP80.dll v8.00.50727.4927 - C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5\MSVCP80.dll
prloader.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\prloader.dll
userenv.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll
params.ppl v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\params.ppl
pxstub.ppl v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\pxstub.ppl
service.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\service.dll
eka_meta.dll v11.0.0.232 - C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2011\eka_meta.dll
ImgUtil.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\ImgUtil.dll
pngfilt.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\pngfilt.dll
mlang.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
mscorlib.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\4ff1f12a08d455f195ba996fe77497c6\mscorlib.ni.dll
nlssorting.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
System.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\161c6f80ad93b0505054d244f1c6243c\System.ni.dll
WindowsBase.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\f1f3a74eb37b27b7d05b8ffa941f8473\WindowsBase.ni.dll
PresentationCore.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\7a1eeb425f9318f432afead4b2da965a\PresentationCore.ni.dll
PresentationFramework.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationFramewo#\8357ade60159c25ee88db0aab8686e6d\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
dwrite.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dwrite.dll
wpfgfx_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
PresentationNative_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
msimg32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
System.Xaml.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\d85a3d6ed5bb77f5603e098cccf60bfa\System.Xaml.ni.dll
System.Xml.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\2d7c29ad77c15abfa6a8fe6d24840a91\System.Xml.ni.dll
System.Drawing.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\2fe09cc54a8390b20e380239db34228f\System.Drawing.ni.dll
clrjit.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
PresentationFramework.Aero.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationFramewo#\b4e58d1a3e0ee75b6b107585c92c68e8\PresentationFramework.Aero.ni.dll
d3d9.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll
d3d8thk.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\d3d8thk.dll
nvd3dum.dll v8.17.12.5896 - C:\Windows\System32\nvd3dum.dll
System.Core.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\85693dfd9ba4905b0fd947fdb51446d5\System.Core.ni.dll
System.Data.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data\c12e10c218be4be353975af6abb072d9\System.Data.ni.dll
System.Data.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
WtsApi32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\WtsApi32.dll
WINSTA.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
UIAutomationProvider.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationProvider\b56a80a51f412ce3832eddecb9bf1580\UIAutomationProvider.ni.dll
UIAutomationTypes.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationTypes\bbd68c1c06eb762bedb74bc73dc9a414\UIAutomationTypes.ni.dll
System.Data.Linq.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data.Linq\73dd24232790e0e5c2649dde8e65516c\System.Data.Linq.ni.dll
System.Configuration.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\ac2cd19f2159d48684e17cbdecfaa3b7\System.Configuration.ni.dll
System.Transactions.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Transactions\40ab9da3eafd6bd1cbc6695ba406975a\System.Transactions.ni.dll
System.Transactions.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
diasymreader.dll v10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll

---

i believe it is an error of Sql Server but i check out all option about it but not luck.
Do you have any suggestion how to work out this step?

Thanks o much for your attention.

Have a good time.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [security in XAML browser applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx#xbap_security_considerations) .